# Are Sidekiq jobs ever pruned / removed from the Failure Queue?

Tags: sidekiq

Very simple question, but I don't know enough about how Sidekiq works to answer it effectively.

Assuming my redis instance (used by Sidekiq) is setup to never expire data, would a Sidekiq job ever be evicted from the failure queue?

i.e. is there a limit, or a setting, or anything anywhere that would cause this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "failure queue" in Sidekiq.  Jobs stay in the retry set for as long as they are retrying.  Once they exhaust their retries, they move to the dead set.  Jobs are pruned from the dead set after 6 months or 10,000 entries.  Review the Error Handling page for details:

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Error-Handling